# How to force restart an iPhone with broken home button

Tags: iphone, restart

Earlier today I was on my iPhone and it randomly froze so I turned it off. When I went to unlock it it wouldn't move. I couldn't unlock it or tap anything. So now I can only stay on the lock screen. I read on the Apple website that I should "force restart" it by pressing my home button and power button at the same time. The problem is my home button is stuck and doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Your referenced question is about iPods and this one about iPods. No duplicate.